# Converting OSM data to GTFS?

Tags: openstreetmap, general-transit-feed-specification

I'm working on OTP. I would like to create a graph for Munich (which requieres GTFS and OSM data).

However, there is no gtfs available, so do you know how to convert osm data to GTFS?

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/57184/osm-to-gtfs

Answer (score 3):

GTFS data is essentially timetables, and OSM doesn't contain timetables, so no.

Answer (score 0):

There is now [osm2gtfs](https://github.com/grote/osm2gtfs#readme) that could help you.

> Use public transport data from OpenStreetMap and external schedule
> information to create a General Transit Feed (GTFS).
>
> The script retrieves current data about public transport networks
> directly from OpenStreetMap via the Overpass API. It stores the data
> in python objects and caches on disk for efficient re-use. Then the
> data is combined with another source of schedule (time) information in
> order to create a GTFS file using the transitfeed library.
>
> For every new city a new configuration file needs to be created.
> Additionally, schedule information should be provided. By-default the
> schedule information is expected to be provided in a certain format.
> However other formats are supported through extending the code. For
> any city and schedule format the script can be easily extended, see
> the developer documentation for more information.

See also [transportr.app contribute](https://transportr.app/contribute/) page that also links to [a video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nd3WcTt8IU) of making your own GTFS feed using osm2gtfs